# Join columns to a table in parallel

Tags: kdb, qpython, rethinkdb-python, qpython3

Currently I use a function to run an `aj` join for a single column from a large table on to a smaller table which has its time column shifted `t` milliseconds ahead, joining on a `sym` column as well as time. I then compute and programatically name a new column based on this joined column, before deleting the original joined column from the small table. This returns the small table with a new column based on values joined from the larger table `t` milliseconds ahead.

I then use an Over loop `/` to repeat this over a list of different delays `t`, recursively adding one new column for each delay in the list, passing as an argument the table so columns are added recursively.

My issue is the query, join and processing are slow on a large table. I have many cores so I would like to parallelise this operation to take advantage of all available cores, as well as optimising the steps taken to add the new columns. The large table is partitioned on disk by `date` and `sym`.

[Edit:] Here is an example of what I have at the moment.

```
smallT: ([] sym: (20#`AAPL),(20#`MSFT); time: (asc 00:00:00+20?til 100), (asc 00:00:00+20?til 100));

bigT: ([] sym: (100#`AAPL),(100#`MSFT); time: (asc 00:00:00+til 100), (asc 00:00:00+til 100); price: (til 100),(til 100));

delays: 00:00:00 + (7 * til 5);

foo: ([bigTab; smallTab2; delays]

    smallTab2: aj[ `sym`time; `sym`time xasc select from (update time:time+delays from smallTab2); `sym`time xasc select sym, time, future pricesprice from bigTabl;

    smallTab2: ![smallTab2; (); 0b; enlist[$"colnametime_", string(`int$delays)] ! enlist(%;`future_price;100)];

    delete future_price from smallTab2

}[bigT];

smallT:foo/[select from smallT; delays];

smallT
```

I am relatively new to q and kdb so verbose explanations of how and why a solution works with working code on a toy example would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: In most cases if you find an aj to be slow it means it's not being used optimally and/or the on-disk table doesn't have the required attributes set up correctly. However, I think it will be better for *you* to provide the example rather than the responders. We need to see exactly what your aj looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is repeatedly sorting the tables inside the loop which will slow you down.

Also as noted in documentation attributes should be applied on the tables which will greatly improve performance.
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/aj/#performance

Rather than looping through the delay offsets you can instead create the full list and only `aj` once.
https://community.kx.com/t5/New-kdb-q-users-question-forum/How-do-you-start-thinking-in-vectors/td-p/12722

```
smallT: ([] sym: (20#`AAPL),(20#`MSFT); time: (asc 00:00:00+20?til 100), (asc 00:00:00+20?til 100));
bigT: ([] sym: (100#`AAPL),(100#`MSFT); time: (asc 00:00:00+til 100), (asc 00:00:00+til 100); price: (til 100),(til 100));
delays: 00:00:00 + (7 * til 5);

bigT:update `p#sym from `sym`time xasc bigT

res:raze {[x;y] update row:i, delay:(`$"delay_",string`int$y),time+y from x}[smallT] each delays
res:update `g#sym from `sym`time xasc res

res:aj[ `sym`time;res; select sym, time, price from bigT]

delete row from `sym`time xcols 0!(exec ({`$"delay_",string`int$x} each delays)#(delay!price) by row:row from res) lj 1!select row,sym,time from res
sym  time     delay_0 delay_7 delay_14 delay_21 delay_28
--------------------------------------------------------
AAPL 00:00:17 17      24      31       38       45      
AAPL 00:00:18 18      25      32       39       46      
AAPL 00:00:18 18      25      32       39       46      
AAPL 00:00:28 28      35      42       49       56      
AAPL 00:00:33 33      40      47       54       61       
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent response. On a small table I find your code to be marginally slower but on my large dataset this is more than an order of magnitude faster. I have accepted your answer, but could you please explain what is happening in the last line? Also the ‘future_price % 100’ in my example represents a computation I need to perform involving other columns, how would this be incorporated in your code?

Comment: The last line pivots the table https://code.kx.com/q/kb/pivoting-tables/ then it joins the sym column back in place https://code.kx.com/q/ref/lj/